# Can someone explain this program to check unique chars in string c++

Tags: c++

Hi I used to solve string char uniqueness using map in C++. I found this solution somewhere and working fine. But I can not understand how it is working. Please some one explain.

```
bool isUnique(string s){
    int check = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i){
        if(s[i] != ' '){
            int val = s[i]-'a';
            if( (check & ( 1 << val)) > 0) return false;
            check = check | (1 << val);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It returns true if string has no repeated character excluding spaces otherwise returns false.

Comment: Where you got the code from didn't explain anything?  You know you can also step through the code with a debugger and see what is going on.

Comment: What is your definition of uniqueness?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no.

Comment: `check` is use as bitfield (assuming `sizeof(int) >= 4`) and flag each (lower) letters. Code is broken for non lower/non space characters though.

Answer (score 4):

It is using an int as if it were a bitmap.  A bitmap is certainly a better data structure for a character uniqueness test than a map.  An int is a crude and questionable (in this case) substitute for a bitmap.

Assume an int has 32 bits.  Those bits are allocated in this code for the first 32 characters beginning with lower case 'a'.  So the upper case letters and most special characters have no bit positions and are treated as unique by this code even if they are not unique.

If you only care about uniqueness for lower case letters, and you are sure the code is only used in architectures that have at least 32 bits in an int, then this is a decent approach.  Otherwise, when you want an array of bits, use some actual array of bits.

Comment: It even worst with special characters as `1 << too_big_number` is UB.